# Displaying the choice of a Dropdownlist in a label using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, label

I have a dropdownlist and I want that when my document is loaded the value currently selected in the dropdown be in the label.

I have a script as

```
    var x  = document.getElementById('vatRate'); 

    document.getElementById('pricingConsumerVat').textContent = x;
```

I get the value in the variable x, however I am not able to display the same in my label.

Why so ?

My label is as

```
<label id="pricingConsumerVat"></label>
```

Any jQuery solutions is most welcomed too.

Comment: Your `x`is `HTMLinputObject` you need to set `x.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById('pricingConsumerVat').textContent = x.value;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('pricingConsumerVat').innerHTML = x.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x  = document.getElementById('vatRate'); 

document.getElementById('pricingConsumerVat').innerHTML = x.value;
```